# How do I write "amartia" in polytonic Greek

Tags: greek

I want `$\alpha\mu\alpha\rho\tau\iota\alpha$` with accent aigu ' above the `$\iota$`. How?

Comment: Please provide an MWE! What is an appropriate `? could you show such a iota as an image or explain its usage? What have you tried, what font do you use, where are you having problems?

Comment: See here: http://biblehub.com/greek/266.htm

An MWE is besides the point here. There must be some standard procedure.

Comment: There are not many cases in which an MWE is besides the point. And this is certainly not one of those cases.

Comment: Note that math mode ($...$) is not appropriate for typesetting Greek words, just as it's not appropriate for italicizing words in the Roman alphabet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Load `babel` for polytonic Greek. Depending on your preferences, you can use the transliteration or direct input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{<amart'ia}

\textgreek{ἁμαρτία}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off topic, but the space between rho and tau looks big compared with the space between alpha and rho in the αρτ in the middle

Comment: @Henry Font design; probably the author had different ideas, but I too consider it a bit uneven; also the space between mu and alpha is not really good.

Answer (score 15):

You could load any font which supports these letters with help of the package `fontspec` (which requires Lua- or XeLaTeX):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}    

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{EB Garamond}
    ἁμαρτία

    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    ἁμαρτία
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you do not want to type the letters (or can't), you may define macros with their [unicodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Extended):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}    

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \symbol{"03B1}%
    \symbol{"03AC}%
    \symbol{"1F00}\symbol{"1F01}\symbol{"1F02}\symbol{"1F03}\symbol{"1F04}\symbol{"1F05}\symbol{"1F06}\symbol{"1F07}%
    \symbol{"1F70}\symbol{"1F71}%

    \symbol{"1F80}\symbol{"1F81}\symbol{"1F82}\symbol{"1F83}\symbol{"1F84}\symbol{"1F85}\symbol{"1F86}\symbol{"1F87}%
    \symbol{"1FB0}\symbol{"1FB1}\symbol{"1FB2}\symbol{"1FB3}\symbol{"1FB4}\symbol{"1FB6}\symbol{"1FB7}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}   
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{καὶ μὴ εἰσενέγκῃς ἡμᾶς εἰς πειρασμόν, ἀλλὰ ῥῦσαι ἡμᾶς ἀπὸ τοῦ πονηροῦ.}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Πάτερ ἡμῶν ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς· ἁγιασθήτω τὸ ὄνομά σου·\\
ἐλθέτω ἡ βασιλεία σου·\\
γενηθήτω τὸ θέλημά σου, ὡς ἐν οὐρανῷ, καὶ ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς·\\
τὸν ἄρτον ἡμῶν τὸν ἐπιούσιον δὸς ἡμῖν σήμερον·\\
καὶ ἄφες ἡμῖν τὰ ὀφειλήματα ἡμῶν,\\
ὡς καὶ ἡμεῖς ἀφίεμεν τοῖς ὀφειλέταις ἡμῶν·\\
καὶ μὴ εἰσενέγκῃς ἡμᾶς εἰς πειρασμόν, ἀλλὰ ῥῦσαι ἡμᾶς ἀπὸ τοῦ πονηροῦ.\\
Ἀμήν.\\
\end{verse} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you type those greek words with all the diacritics in the source code?

Comment: @rmdmc89 I have copy pasted that from somewhere. Some translater, I guess. Can't remember. My keyboard does not provide me such nice letters.