# How to write a sentence in Greek script using the MastersDoctoralThesis document class

Tags: packages, fontspec, babel, document-classes, greek

I am writing my master thesis and I want to write down a sentence in Greek.
Some years ago I used in another project for the same situation:

```
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
```

and when I had to write in Greek I was using:

```
\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{...}
```

In my current project instead I have this kind of settings:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, ...]
```

What I just tried to do then is adding the `polutonikogreek` to the document class. Unfortunately it didn't work. By searching online then I found people saying to add the `greek.polutoniko` and so it became:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, greek.polutoniko, ...]
```

And the package is loaded. Then, in order to write the text in Greek, I should use:

```
\textgreek{...}
```

Unfortunately `\textgreek{}` is a call not recognized. So I moved forward and I saw some answers saying to use:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

but it gives me back the error:

```
The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
"lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
```

So, at the end I wasn't able to write my sentence in Greek. Can you help me understanding how to do it please? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is my whole document class

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing, headsepline, ]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
```

Comment: Have you used `xelatex` or `lualatex` then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no, my bad. pdflatex is in my requirements. Sorry for forgetting to write it down

Comment: Is pdflatex really in your requirements, or an engine which outputs a  .pdf file?

Comment: See [How do I write “amartia” in polytonic Greek](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210843/4778), does it help?

Comment: @Bernard it really is in my requirements unfortunately

Comment: @Alenanno that's where I learned about the "\textgreek{...}" thing, which unfortunately seems not working in my project

Comment: @EnricoRibelli You were adding `greek.polutoniko` to the document class, you should add it to the `babel` options. Please copy-paste the document in that answer and test it in another empty file.

Comment: @Alenanno that's what I did at the beginning after reading that post. but it gave me the error "Error: Option clash for package babel." so I went looking it up on google and I found out that error is because my documentclass already calls babel. The answer is in the following link and that's why I added it to the documentclass http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135060/getting-an-option-clash-with-babel-english-greek

Comment: @EnricoRibelli Then you're not using the `article` class? Please replace all the small code snippets in your question with a MWE (minimal working example). In this case it will be non-working, but load your document class and the sentence you want to write.

Comment: @Alenanno yes I am not using the article class. Edited the question with my document class. For the sentence don't worry, it's just an euforism in ancient greek.

Comment: I'd try `\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,main=english]{babel}`. Is the class available somewhere?

Comment: Instead of asking again the same question, you should point where the class is available; there's no way to answer without this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single sentence in Greek you don't need to load `babel-greek`. If you are using UTF-8 as the file encoding you can use the first way; otherwise use the transliteration below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

{\textgreekfont Πάτερ ἡμῶν ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς}

{\textgreekfont\catcode`~=12 P'ater <hm~wn <o >en to~is o>urano~is}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This definitely solved my question! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 4):

Your custom class is already loading `babel` at line 155:

[image]

So if you load it again in your document, you get an `Option Clash` error. Now, a good rule of thumb is never to edit classes or packages, so to circumvent this, you can add `\PassOptionsToPackage` before the `\documentclass` is declared.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{greek.polutoniko, main=english}{babel}
\documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing, headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Cosmos in Greek is \textgreek{Κόσμος}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a choice but to edit the class or package, though.  I have encountered a journal style file that redefines `\p@` (among other cardinal sins...)

Comment: @zwol If the license of the class allows you to change it, you are free to do so. If a journal class redefines stuff, they have a pretty good reason. I wouldn't touch it. They won't care about your changes.

Comment: @Johannes_B You maybe don't realize how disastrous redefining things in the guts of LaTeX can be...

Comment: @zwol I surely do. And i know, i can't simply change lines of *The Lord of the Rings*, and say it is the same. There are issues.

Comment: @Johannes_B In the not-at-all-hypothetical situation with the journal style file that redefined `\p@`, what I did was fix it (with each change from the original clearly marked) and then put a README in with the sources to warn them that the document won't compile if they put back their version.  And we'll see what happens. :-/

Comment: @zwol See, you did everything right. You helped them. :-)