# Command \textalpha unavailable in encoding T1 when using Greek

Tags: unicode, greek

I am trying to configure the `MastersDoctoralThesis` class in overleaf to accept greek character (My thesis has to be written in Greek).

What I did was to add the option `greek` when opening the document class. like that

```
\documentclass[greek,english,
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt,
...,
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
```

I also use the packages above

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default
```

When I add some greek characters in the title I get

> LaTeX Error: Command \textalpha unavailable in encoding T1.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: T1 is a latin encoding and has no Greek, but if you add `\usepackage[greek]{babel}` (which you will need anyway) it should add the LGR encoding which has Greek.

Comment: If I add `\usepackage[greek]{babel}`  before tha packges mentioned above I get `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel `

Comment: It's hard to debug fragments it is always best to make a small complete document that shows the error.

Comment: Ι used `\usepackage{textgreek}` instead of `\usepackage[greek]{babel}` as a commented that was deleted suggested and this seems to have solved the problem

Comment: I did not see that your thesis is in Greek. Have you come across with http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327234/4427 ? Of course `palatino` is not an option.

Comment: I hadn't seen that. This really accurate. thnx, the problem seems to have been solved using you suggestion though

Comment: Eventually the problem is not solved, when I am trying to use the letter "ο" I get `Command \textomicron unavailable in encoding T1.`

Comment: Add `greek` as the global option after english. Remove package `fontenc`. You get  greek output.

Comment: Is there any news here?